Automate password reset reminder emails
I want to automate sending emails to Customer Community users that their password will expire in 7 days

Our Customer Community users use several different profiles, each with their own Password Policies (90 days expiration, 180 day expiration, etc.)
New Customer Community Profiles get created from time-to-time
I don't want to manage these password policies in CMDT (duplicative metadata management)

So, the plan is to

Use a scheduled-triggered flow on users who have UserType = CspLitePortal

that queried the org metadata ProfilePasswordPolicy for the expiration period (via invocable Apex to bulkify)
compare the expiration period versus user's last password reset date and send email if needed



As far as I know (Winter 25), the only place where the password expiration policy resides is in the org's metadata type ProfilePasswordPolicy (MD doc ref)

How do I retrieve these in a Flow?
Related solution that relies on hard-coding

One solution

Use a Flow element that is an Apex action (i.e. invocable Apex)
Pass the profileIds of all active Customer Community users selected by your flow to the invocable

Invocable Apex meat
I'll skip marshalling the profileIds and then demarshalling the results as that is common knowledge to invocable developers.

You will need to install the github package apex-mdapi

This package was last updated at V42 but fortunately ProfilePasswordPolicy is included as an ApexType as it became available for query in V40.


You'll find countless examples of how to use this package in the repo file MetadataServiceExamples.cls

The MDAPI can fetch metadata synchronously via a Web Service callout.  This callout requires the fullname of the ProfilePasswordPolicy metadata type.  An example of such a fullname is My_Custom_Experience_profilePasswordPolicy1643934087860

The first part of the fullName is the Profile.Name with blanks replaced by underscores (e.g. Profile.Name = My Custom Experience)
The last part of the fullName (e.g. 1643934087860) is a Unix time (long) that is close, but not quite, the Unix time for the Profile's created date - hence ungenerateable from a Profile SObject



// Step 1, get all customerCommunityProfiles
Set<String> customerCommunityProfileFullNames = new Set<String> ();
for (Profile customerCommunityProfile : [SELECT Id, Name, UserType 
                                           FROM Profile 
                                           WHERE UserType = 'CspLitePortal']) {
    // Coerce Profile.Name to look like an API Name
    customerCommunityProfileFullNames.add(customerCommunityProfile.Name.replace(' ','_'));
}

// Step 2 - Establish a MetadataService.MetadataPort object

MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort(); // mdapi service
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

// Step 3 - Get all ProfilePasswordPolicy fullnames (use listMetadata)
List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery> queries = new List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery>();
MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery queryProfilePasswordPolicy = new MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery();
queryProfilePasswordPolicy.type_x = 'ProfilePasswordPolicy';
queries.add(queryProfilePasswordPolicy);

String[] profilePasswordPolicyfullNames = new List<String>();
MetadataService.FileProperties[] fileProperties =
            service.listMetadata(queries, 62); // 62 is MDAPI version
for(MetadataService.FileProperties fileProperty : fileProperties){
    String profilePortionOfFullName = 
            fileProperty.fullName
                        .substringBefore('_profilePasswordPolicy'); // extract profileName from fullname
    
    if (customerCommunityProfileFullNames.contains(profilePortionOfFullName)) { 
        profilePasswordPolicyFullNames.add(fileProperty.fullName);
    }
}    
// At this point, profilePasswordPolicyFullNames contains fullnames of 
//    only Customer Community User Profiles

// Step 3 - retrieve the ProfilePasswordPolicy metadata
MetadataService.ProfilePasswordPolicy[] profilePasswordPolicies = 
    (MetadataService.ProfilePasswordPolicy[]) 
       service.readMetadata('ProfilePasswordPolicy',
                             profilePasswordPolicyFullNames)
    .getRecords();
for (MetadataService.ProfilePasswordPolicy profilePasswordPolicy : profilePasswordPolicies) {
  system.debug(profilePasswordPolicy.fullname + ' w/ expiration:' + profilePasswordPolicy.passwordExpiration);                                                                       
} 

Exercise left to the reader
There are some complications with the above code that you need to consider

The statement that retrieves the ProfilePasswordPolicy metadata is limited to only 10 entries in the list. Otherwise you get:
System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: EXCEEDED_ID_LIMIT: 
record limit reached. cannot submit more than 10 records in this operation faultcode=sf:EXCEEDED_ID_LIMIT faultactor=

Hence you may need to loop and make multiple callouts

Not every Profile will have metadata in ProfilePasswordPolicy.  Their password expiration days can be found in the SecuritySettings file within Settings metadata type (MD doc ref)

In a schedule-triggered flow scenario, the flow has to do a WAIT element before calling the invocable. If you are using OOTB apex MDAPI examples, they rely on UserInfo.getSessionId() and there won't be a sessionId so the SOAP call fails. You need to use Named Credentials with an OAuth Auth Provider.  Groundswell Cloud Solutions has a great post on this (which you can adapt to using client credentials flow)


Postscript
I'm all ears if the SFSE community has an easier solution as the above is fairly complicated for the average SFDC developer.
Related

IDEA: Allow salesforce API to fetch the password policies enabled at profile level
Retrieve ProfilePasswordPolicy via API
Is there any way to fetch fullnames for ProfilePasswordPolicy records using API?
Using Named Credentials with the Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API

